# My integer isn't carrying over between views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am going to be setting up IAP for extra lives in my game, but before I do that I wanted to test to see if it would transfer from my purchasing View Controller to my game View Controller and it's not. In my purchasing VC I have

```
-(void)StartView{
//Life = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Life"]; (If in the code then it will not update the LifeCounter.text)
livesUpdated = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0001 target:self selector:@selector(LiveUpdatedCheck) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)LiveUpdatedCheck{
LifeCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)Life];
}


-(void)LiveUpdatedCheck{
LifeCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)Life];
}


-(IBAction)TenLifePurchase:(id)sender{
    Life = Life + 10;
}
```

Then in my game VC I have

```
-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender{
Life = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Life"];
LifeCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)Life];
}
```

'Life' is declared as an NSInteger in both of my .h files and I used userDefaults just like this to move my high score between 2 view controllers and the same for changing the color of a ball via id integers. How can I fix this problem? Could it be because in-between my purchase controller and my game controller you have to go through a main screen that has no information on 'Life'? Also when you go back to the purchased controller after viewing the game controller it resets back to 0 from whatever number it was, but if you view any other controller then back to purchased then the number will store and not reset back to 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to move global data to singleton class, confining it to a view controller and then trying to access it form another place is not a good idea. You will have to save the data somehow (most preferably by Dylan's method).

Comment: Agreed! This is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually saved the value anywhere. You're just querying for the value both times and not saving it. Here's how to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourIntegerValue
    forKey:@"Life"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Note that you have to call the synchronize method to get it into the database. Hope that helps!

Comment: Does it matter where I put it? Does it go in both VCs or just one? But thanks for the help!

Comment: Wherever you change it, just use this snippet to save the new value over the old one. And when you switch views, query it as you've been doing.